# Selenium : Button color

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, background-color, getattribute

I am trying to get the color of a button before and after mouse hower. I have used the following code.

```java
driver.navigate().to("https://www.leafground.com/button.xhtml");

WebElement color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='j_idt88:j_idt100']//span[@class='ui-button-text ui-c']"));
String before = color.getAttribute("color");
        
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(color).perform();
        
String after = color.getAttribute("style");
System.out.println(before + " " + after);
```

The value after the color change works perfectly but before I am getting blank value. I am confused as I use the same code for both the variables. but, one returning a value and one doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no `color` attribute defined for that element. Not before and not after the hovering over that element. Instead you can take `style` attribute in both cases.
2. Before hovering no `style` attribute presented in that element, but after hovering it presented, so it's correct that you get nothing by applying `.getAttribute("color")` or `.getAttribute("style")` on that element before hovering.
3. To get the color before hovering you can apply `.getCssValue("background-color")` as this is the special attribute containing that color as you can see here

[image]

So, please try the following code:

```java
driver.navigate().to("https://www.leafground.com/button.xhtml");


WebElement color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='j_idt88:j_idt100']//span[@class='ui-button-text ui-c']"));
String before = color.getCssValue("background-color");
    
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(color).perform();
    
String after = color.getAttribute("style");
System.out.println(before + " " + after);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your solution. I tried this now, the value the code returns was "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)" instead of the original value that was present on the html.

Comment: Are you sure you used `color.getCssValue("background-color")`? Maybe it was `color.getCssValue("color")` ?